# Two British passports, two visa

Tags: passports

I have a L1 visa for my work in the USA. I also have a second British passport for my visas to other countries (China).
I have approved visas. What passport do I show when I am leaving USA ? The one with the China visa in it or the one with my work visa?

Comment: The one you entered on, preferably

Comment: Show my British passport with my USA visa in when I'm departing USA ? Then Use my other British passport with my Chinese visa when I enter China.

Comment: Exactly. Much like dual nationality. See http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/52100/36405. Keep in mind the US has no exit check. The airline will do that for you. You may have to also show your passport with the Chinese visa.

Comment: Thanks so much. I forgot there is no immigration exit at US airports. I can always present both passports at checkin with the airline.

Comment: There, written a real answer. I do think your situation is a little uncommon, so it probably wouldn't hurt stressing the airline employee that you must leave on your US visa passport. Have a nice trip!

Comment: what do you mean by two passport ? Both are valid ? I think this is not a situation that can exists... Surely one of them is expired .

Answer (score 3):

This works exactly the same as with dual nationality, see the canonical answer: [I have two passports/nationalities. How do I use them when I travel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/52100/36405). Treat it as case 1.

In this case you entered the USA with your USA visa passport, so you have to use that again when leaving the country (checking in). In China you show your passport with Chinese visa.

Keep in mind that the USA does not have exit checks. The airline will register you instead. So always use the passport you entered on to leave. The airline will also want to see you are allowed into your destination country. Showing your other passport along with a quick explanation will do.